# How to delete a .sdf file created in DataDirectory

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm creating a SQL CE database file programmatically and want to make sure I'm creating a fresh new one each time so I added the delete method. Since each database file is created in `DataDirectory`, I would want to delete the file in `DataDirectory` as well, but it's giving me

**"illegal characters in path"** error

following is my code:

```
/* illegal characters in path */
File.Delete("|DataDirectory|\\Foo2Database.sdf");

string connString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Foo2Database.sdf";
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connString);
engine.CreateDatabase();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|DataDirectory|` is connection string notation and is not related to file system pathes.

You can delete the file using the code like this:

```
 var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
 var fileName = Path.Combine(directoryName, "Foo2Database.sdf");
 File.Delete(fileName);
```

You can get current `DataDirectory` via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");` if you set it.

If you have asp.net `DataDirectory` will be `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");` by default.

Comment: It is there since .NET1.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

Comment: though already using "System.IO" namespace, I still have to use do "System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName"

Comment: This is probably because you have another `Path` class declared.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is network deployed you can use this to get the path for the Data Directory

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

Otherwise you can use this

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```